# Webpack with multiples entries cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

This is my first time setting up webpack, and so far I'm just confused. I'm trying to gather all of my jsx files in their respective files, but webpack seems to think they don't exist...

`webpack --display-error-details`

I get this errors that look like so:

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./static/js/base in /Users/Maude/Projects/School/entry
resolve file
  /Users/Maude/Projects/School/entry/static/js/base.js doesn't exist
  /Users/Maude/Projects/School/entry/static/js/base.jsx doesn't exist
  /Users/Maude/Projects/School/entry/static/js/base is not a file
resolve directory
  /Users/Maude/Projects/School/entry/static/js/base/package.json doesn't exist (directory description file)
  directory default file index
    resolve file index in /Users/Maude/Projects/School/entry/static/js/base
      /Users/Maude/Projects/School/entry/static/js/base/index doesn't exist
      /Users/Maude/Projects/School/entry/static/js/base/index.jsx doesn't exist
      /Users/Maude/Projects/School/entry/static/js/base/index.js doesn't exist
```

My static file structure looks like this:

```
static
  |- js
      |- base
            |- base.jsx
      |- classes
            |- classes.jsx
            |- locations.jsx
      |- students
            |- students.jsx
            |- network.jsx
      |- teachers
            |- teachers.jsx
  |- less
```

And lastly my webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    base: './static/js/base',
    classes: './static/js/classes',
    students: './static/js/students',
    teachers: './static/js/teachers',
  },

  output: {
    path: './static/bundles',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },

  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 3333
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: '/node_modules/',
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['/node_modules/'],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },

}
```

Why am I receiving errors like `ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory'` when they're clearly there? Help obi-wan!

Also my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "--",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "bower": "^1.7.9",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-bower": "0.0.13",
    "gulp-changed": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-cssmin": "^0.1.7",
    "gulp-html-replace": "^1.6.1",
    "gulp-less": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-react": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.5.4",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.5.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.4",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: How does your `package.json` file look ? Also, do you need the comma after the closing tag of your `resolve` attribute ?

Comment: @ODelibalta updated to include package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you only need the one entry file, base.jsx, unless you have an extra index file in your structure.

webpack will crawl through the imports and build up the tree structure from that

```
entry: './static/js/base.jsx'
```

edit: for a single entry point you want the file that has something like:

```
React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app')
```

from your packaged.json, it looks like it might be index.js, if so then you put in webpack.config.js

```
entry: './index.js'
```

then webpack should pull in the entire react app by following the import statements to build the complete bundle file.

btw. there is no real need to use .jsx file extensions. Just use .js. It means you also don't need to worry about the extensions field in webpack

btw2. why are you mixing gulp and webpack? Never seen that before. Maybe better to go either the gulp/browserify route, or just stick to webpack.

Comment: and then from within base.jsx import all my components? could get lengthly if multiple components like... static/js/classes > classes.jsx, locations.jsx

Comment: ok, i see from your package.json, you have an index.js. If index.js is the file where you attach the react app to the html DOM then this is the entry point for the webpack. I am pretty sure you will only need one entry point:

Comment: removed it. `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type`

Comment: i'm not saying your wrong. but webpack allow multiple entry points. I just wish it worked lol

Comment: i'd remove gulp if i get webpack to work. fingers crossed

Comment: i just wanted to thank you for your help. i think i got it working with multiple entries (not working 100%, more errors ahead).

Comment: ok, i edited my post above. try just using one entry point, it should be the file where you attach the react app to the DOM. The missing loader could be the cssloader and lessloader that is missing. You will need it if any of your jsx files are importing css

Comment: I tried with one entry point. Returned `ERROR in ./static/js/base/base.jsx
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react'` so... progress? :)

Comment: if you are still not getting anywhere, maybe you could show the contents of index.js and base.jsx

Comment: also, maybe try installing react? I don't think gulp-react will be enough for webpack

Comment: its not you're right. ran `npm install --save-dev react react-dom`